# A proposal for a voting index

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

Downvoting seems to be a rather popular activity on MSE. In the few informal discussions I have seen there seems to be a base of support for this, *and also* for the preservation of (optional) anonymity for users of the feature. I am happy with this state of affairs, but I think it would be useful for each user to have a publicly visible index representing the function $$f_{:-(}:MSE \to $\mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,+1]$$ defined by:
$$f_{:-(}(user) = \frac{upvotes-downvotes}{upvotes+downvotes}$$

This would preserve anonymity for individual votes, whilst ensuring that those who contribute most to the site by casting downvotes are given the recognition they deserve.

added: This function is defined in terms of the votes *cast* by a particular user. There is a dual function $f*$ which has the same definition, but is computed on the basis of the votes *received* by the user in question.

added: I notice that after only 3 minutes and four views that this question has already received an anonymous downvote. This indicates the great importance of the downvoting activity as a stimulus to useful discussion.

Comment: I suppose You are aware of the fact that on each [user profile page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/79543/david-holden) you can see number of upvotes and number of downvotes (in the part named *Votes Cast*).

Comment: BTW I have tried to add capitalization to your post, but you reverted it in your next edit [each time](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/12333/revisions). It might have been just an accident - of several edits colliding. But in any case I wanted to ask whether there is a reason to avoid capitalized letters at the beginning of sentence.

Comment: @Martin I did not decapitalize deliberately.

Comment: the next comment is the full edit of the above comment, which that damned 5-minute rule prevented me from posting

Comment: -1 Now you have a nonanonymous downvote too.

Comment: due to a neurological problem in the C4/C5 region of the cervical chord i experience much frustration in the use of both keyboard and mouse (particularly, but by no means exclusively, the CAPSLOCK issue) and have simplified my practice accordingly. the browser I am using automatically capitalizes the word "i". I capitalize proper names, and am scrupulous when quoting.  spend a lot of time correcting minor typos, an activity fortunately hidden from the wider world.

Comment: I find it singularly ironic that intelligent people who think nothing of using a set theory without the axiom of choice, are emotionally disturbed by an English sentence without an (informationally redundant) initial upper case letter.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker thank you. your index is 0.71

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I also notice that your comment "Now you have a nonanonymous downvote too", though correctly capitalized, implies an unnecessarily ad hominem approach to voting. surely good practice is to vote according to your assessment of questions and answers rather than of persons.

Comment: @DavidHolden I happen to disagree with the proposal. Coincidentally, I also don't like your sarcasm.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you Martin for pointing out that the information is already available for computing $f_{:-(}$ (though, not, I think $f*_{:-(}$). your f-value is 0.95, which seems intuitively about right for a responsible senior member of a community like MSE

Comment: @DavidHolden I think you have used votes on meta for calculation. (For me it is (1351-36)/(1351+36)=0.948.) I thought you want to talk about upvotes/downvotes on the main site. (That would be (8782-16)/(8782+16)=0.996.) I suppose you did the same thing when you calculated 0.71 for Michael.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker perhaps there is a clash of assumptions here. my understanding (possibly naïve because I am new here) was that votes were given according to the quality of formulation of questions. your comment indicates that you understand votes on proposals are part of a quasi-democratic decision process. as you have more experience you may be correct in this. as to what you refer to as my sarcasm, I thank you for sharing your opinion, and can assure you that I am a libertarian on questions of taste rather than fact. i.e. I hold you to be free to dislike whatever you wish.

Comment: @DavidHolden Yes, votes on meta are usually interpreted as signs of agreement/disagreement. Also, voting on meta has no effect on anyones reputation count.

Comment: Voting on meta has different meaning, see [What is meta](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) in help center and also [this older question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/718/what-does-it-mean-to-downvote-a-question-on-meta).

Comment: @MartinSleziak (+1)thank you for pointing out that methodological subtlety which indeed I had missed. quite generally I have noticed that many of my mistakes can be traced back to faulty or incomplete assumptions.

Comment: BTW various SEDE queries could be made to compute the index you have suggested, for example by modifying these queries: [upvote / downvote ratio](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/65203/upvote-downvote-ratio) and [Ratio of Upvotes to Downvotes Received](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/6014/ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-received)

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes, clearly I need to do some homework on how the site works. my temperament is rather that of the fool who rushes in rather than the angel who fears to tread. and your hypothesis re downvotes on meta vs on the main site is also reinforced by evidence. Michael's f-score on the main site is much higher, 0.86. my apologies for any offence or discomfort I may have caused as a consequence of my ignorance of the modus operandi

Comment: @MartinSleziak I tried the SEDE query modification you suggested, and it was unexpectedly straightforward. thank you for that useful suggestion, and for making me aware that this easy-to-use data exploration facility exists.

Comment: @DavidHolden In that case, you could perhaps add links to the queries to your post. (Either edit them into the question, or post them as answers.)

Comment: As @MartinSleziak points out, your index is calculable from public information, and besides, I don't see any added benefit to the formula you're proposing over simply looking at a user's vote counts.  Unless I'm misinterpreting, it seems the core of what you're proposing is equivalent to showing the upvote/downvote tallies next to a user's name in all their posts, and I can only interpret that as an attempt to punish people for anonymous downvoting, which is stupid.  So, here's another -1.

Comment: @DavidHolden I really, really dislike double standards. You expect understanding from others for your keyboard/mouse issue, but you blithely assign "emotionally disturbed" to those who find the resulting text difficult to read. If you attack those who might have difficulties reading your text for a variety of reasons, then you rightfully deserve to accept attacks for missing capitals in silence. To talk about "redundant information" shows a serious lack of empathy for other people. As it so happens, the voting index is redundant information as well.

Comment: @DavidHolden You can go to data.SE like everyone else to find out who primarily downvotes others. If you think that this is difficult, why should we care? You do not care whether someone else finds your text difficult to read and call them emotionally disturbed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, Stack Exchange network (4.6 million users) does not customize its interface to individual user's preference. However, users are able to customize the interface themselves with client-side scripts. In particular, you can add the f-score to each user profile in this way:

[image: example]

I actually like the effect, maybe I'll be using this myself. The script I wrote for this purpose is below. It relies on jQuery library. I can turn it into a Chrome extension if you want, but adding it to other browsers (e.g., Firefox) is out of my range of activities.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var entries, f, up, down;
    $('.votes-cast-stats').each(function () {
        entries = [];
        $('td', this).each(function () {
            entries.push($(this).html());
        });
    });
    up = entries[entries.indexOf('up') - 1];
    up = parseInt(up.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
    down = entries[entries.indexOf('down') - 1];
    down = parseInt(down.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
    f = ((up - down) / (up + down)).toPrecision(3);
    $('.user-profile-stats').append('<tr><th></th><td>f-score</td><td>' + f + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: thank you for that very useful post. I don't know anything about client-side scripts at present, but this may serve as a motivating example to encourage me to learn how to do it during 2014

Comment: :-o  Whoever you are, Post No Bulls, you are constantly earning my respect. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here, [have a data explorer query to play with](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/157869/lowest-50-f-with-over-1000-rep).